# PHP MySQL delete redirect to blank page

Tags: php, mysql, form-submit, delete-row

I have a slight problem with my php script. I have a table that generates rows populated by a MySql statement.

At the last column I have a button for edit, and delete. My problem is when I hit delete, the query works successfully but it redirects me to a blank page!

The header location is correct but when I hit delete it stays on the current page, but it is just a plain white page.

```
<?php foreach($rows as $row): ?> 
<tr> 
    <td>
        <form action="" method="post"> <?php echo $row['id']; ?> </form>
    </td>
    <td>
        <form action="" method="post"> <?php echo $row['roleid']; ?> </form>
    </td>
    <td>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <?php echo htmlentities($row['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>
        </form>
    </td>
    <td>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <?php echo htmlentities($row['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>
        </form>
    </td>
    <td>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input name="Edit" type="submit" value="Edit" />
            <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" />
        </form>
    </td>
</tr> 
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And I can successfully set a session using:

```
if (isset($_POST['Edit'])) {

$_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['id'];
header("Location: edit_account.php");

}
```

But it seems I have ran into another problem:( I also want to add a delete button on each row to delete that user account. Right now this is how it looks:

```
<td> <form action="" method="post">
        <input name="Delete" type="submit" value="Delete" />
        <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" />
    </form> </td>
```

And the php code used is:

```
if (isset($_POST['Delete'])) {
    // Everything below this point in the file is secured by the login system 

    // We can retrieve a list of members from the database using a SELECT query. 
    // In this case we do not have a WHERE clause because we want to select all 
    // of the rows from the database table. 
    $query = " 
        DELETE 
        FROM user
        WHERE
            id = :id 
    "; 

    // The parameter values 
    $query_params = array( ':id' => $_POST['id'] ); 

    try { 
        // These two statements run the query against your database table. 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    }

    catch(PDOException $ex) { 
        // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
        // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    } 

    // Finally, we can retrieve all of the found rows into an array using fetchAll 
    $rows = $stmt->fetch(); 

    // This redirects the user back to the members-only page after they register 
    header("Location: ../adminindex.php"); 

    // Calling die or exit after performing a redirect using the header function 
    // is critical.  The rest of your PHP script will continue to execute and 
    // will be sent to the user if you do not die or exit. 
    die("Redirecting to adminindex.php.php"); 
}
```

My problem is the redirection! When I click on the Delete button it actually runs the query but afterwards it just redirects to **memberlist.php** but the page is blank!?

Why would this be happening? Is there something I am missing?I have tried changing the header location with no success.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't see  a redirect in your PHP

Comment: Do you have some type of user validation on that page? By deleting the user are they somehow messing that session up?

Comment: Try using absolute HTTP paths instead of relative paths in the header('location...') function. For example, instead of ../adminindex.php change it to http://yoursite.com/adminindex.php

Comment: The header location is the redirect. Relative pathnames are fine for now. Will change later

Answer (score -1):

`die("Redirecting to adminindex.php.php");`  ??

Why don't you use a switch?
like this:

```
switch($action){
    case 'delete':
        //your code here
    break;
    case 'edit':
        //your code here
    break;
}
```

and to do the delete button:

```
echo $row['username'] ."<a href=page.php?action=delete&id=".$row['id']."><img src=some fancy img></a>";
```

Comment: I would prefer to stay away from case statements. For the delete button why are you echoing $row['username']?

Comment: I thought he wanted the delete button after the other output. Just an example. But you're right, now that I've took a closer look it would be better to just do if(isset